# Trouble deserializing Json from Google Analytics

Tags: java, json, serialization, google-analytics

Hi I'm attempting to deserializer.deserialize this data from Google Analytics

> [[/s417, 14945, 93.17823577906019], [/s413, 5996, 72.57178438000356],
>   [/s417/, 3157, 25.690567351200837], [/s420, 2985, 44.12472727272727],
>   [/s418, 2540, 64.60275150472916], [/s416, 2504, 69.72643979057591],
>   [/s415, 2379, 44.69660861594867], [/s422, 2164, 57.33786505538772],
>   [/s421, 2053, 48.18852894317578], [/s414, 1839, 93.22588376273218],
>   [/s412, 1731, 54.8431860609832], [/s411, 1462, 71.26186830015314],
>   [/s419, 1423, 51.88551401869159], [/, 63, 11.303571428571429],
>   [/s420/, 22, 0.3333333333333333], [/s413/, 21, 7.947368421052632],
>   [/s416/, 16, 96.0], [/s421/, 15, 0.06666666666666667], [/s411/, 13,
>   111.66666666666667], [/s422/, 13, 0.07692307692307693], [/g150, 11, 0.09090909090909091], [/s414/, 10, 2.0], [/s418/, 10, 0.4444444444444444], [/s415/, 9, 0.2222222222222222], [/s412/, 8, 0.6666666666666666], [/s45, 6, 81.0], [/s164, 5, 45.25], [/s28, 5, 16.2], [/s39, 5, 25.2], [/s27, 4, 59.5], [/s29, 4, 26.5], [/s365, 3, 31.666666666666668], [/s506, 3, 23.333333333333332], [/s1139, 2, 30.5], [/s296, 2, 11.0], [/s311, 2, 13.5], [/s35, 2, 55.0], [/s363, 2, 15.5], [/s364, 2, 17.5], [/s419/, 2, 0.0], [/s44, 2, 85.5], [/s482, 2, 28.5], [/s49, 2, 29.5], [/s9, 2, 77.0], [/s146, 1, 13.0], [/s228, 1, 223.0], [/s229, 1, 54.0], [/s231, 1, 0.0], [/s30, 1, 83.0], [/s312, 1, 15.0], [/s313, 1, 155.0], [/s316, 1, 14.0], [/s340, 1, 22.0], [/s350, 1, 0.0], [/s362, 1, 24.0], [/s43, 1, 54.0], [/s442, 1, 87.0], [/s465,
>   1, 14.0], [/s468, 1, 67.0], [/s47, 1, 41.0], [/s71, 1, 16.0], [/s72,
>   1, 16.0], [/s87, 1, 48.0], [/s147, 0, 0.0], [/s417, 0, 0.0]]

With this

```
   @Immutable
       private static JSONDeserializer<List<List<String>>> deserializer = new JSONDeserializer<List<List<String>>>();
```

And it's failing silently on the deserialization.

Only error I'm getting is from the xhtml

> ```
> com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback
> ```
>
> visit
>       SEVERE: javax.el.ELException: /views/guide/edit.xhtml @257,102 value="#{GuideEditController.visitsByScene}": flexjson.JSONException:
>   Missing value at character 2

Any clues?

Comment: I don't think `/s417` is valid value. Wrap those in quotes like `"/s417"`

Comment: Any clue how to do that when it's in the JSON? .replace on the string?

Comment: Do you receive this string as is and have no control over it?

Comment: Yes this is how it comes out of the API

Comment: That's strange, because it is really NOT a valid JSON string.

Comment: What's the purpose of those `/s`s? Maybe you could just remove those with a simple string replace and then try parse.

Comment: This did it.. replaceAll("[^\\d,\\[\\]\\,]+", ""); Add your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 0):

marekful had the right idea

replaceAll("[^\d,[]\,]+", "") to remove the offending characters did the trick